# Microsoft graph API for getting the gamertag

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want any Microsoft Graph API/Microsoft Service that should return Gamertag in response to that Microsoft account

Answer (score 1):

A gamertag is the term related to the Xbox world, so I would recommend you to use [Xbox services API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/live/concepts/xbox-services-api/live-introduction-to-xbox-live-apis). The Graph API doesn't provide any access to Xbox services.

Read the [user's profile settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/reference/live/rest/uri/profilev2/uri-usersbatchprofilesettings). The [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/reference/live/rest/json/json-profile) resource has the property [gamertag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/reference/live/rest/json/json-profile#:%7E:text=display%20in%20games.-,Gamertag,-string).